# Beautifulsoup extracting

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have a few simple bs questions (1-3 go together and 4-6 go together).  Suppose I have the HTML with the structure as follows:

```
<meta property="tall"/>
<meta property="wide" content="spiral"/>
<meta name="red"/>
<meta name="tall"/>
```

1. How can I find all of the instances of `property`?
2. How can I then extract `"tall"` and `"wide"`?
3. How can I then extract `property`?
4. How can I find all of the instances of `"tall"`?
5. How can I then extract `name` and `property`
6. How can I then extract `"tall"`?

   What I can easily do is extract all instances of meta:

   ```
   soup1.find_all("meta")
   ```

   But, after that, I have to access each element of the resulting list and then I can get the things like `property` and `name`.  But I would rather skip this step and directly get all instances of `property` and `name` if possible.
7. Finally, if I want to get the url from a website using `requests.get`, and it is a website that you have to click on a button at the bottom to make it load more, and I want the extra stuff, how can I make this happen?

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ is probably a good place to start...

Comment: This is probably too much questions per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert at using BeautifulSoup but I gave it a try and here's what I came up with, which is hopefully enough to get you started. Just be aware that there might me more elegant solutions.

Boilerplate:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

a = """<meta property="tall"/>
<meta property="wide" content="spiral"/>
<meta name="red"/>
<meta name="tall"/>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
```

Questions:

I.

```
p = soup.findAll('meta', attrs = {"property":re.compile('.*')})
>> [<meta property="tall"/>, <meta content="spiral" property="wide"/>]
```

II.

```
ex = [p[i]['property'] for i in range(len(p))]
>> ['tall', 'wide']
```

III. I'm not sure what you mean, maybe it's covered already?

IV.

```
alltall = soup.findAll('meta', attrs = {'name':'tall'})
alltall += (soup.findAll('meta', attrs = {'property':'tall'}))
>> [<meta name="tall"/>, <meta property="tall"/>]
```

V./VI. I spent some time searching but did not find an elegant way to do it this way around. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

`Beautiful soup` is all about playing around with extracting data but here is something to start with:

Here `test.html` is your content that you posted. The reason it has a `try, catch block` is because if the find operation fails then instead of printing a error it prints nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open(r'd:\test.html','r'))
#print soup.prettify()

items = soup.findAll("meta")

try:
    print "#How can I find all of the instances of property?"
    for all_prop in items:
        if all_prop['property']:
            print all_prop
except:
    print ""

try:
    print "#How can I then extract tall and wide?"
    for properties in items:
        print(properties['property'])
except:
    print ""


try:
    print "#all of the instances of tall"
    print soup.findAll('meta', attrs = {'property':'tall'})
    print soup.findAll('meta', attrs = {'name':'tall'})
    print ""
except:
    print ""

try:
    print "#How can I then extract tall?"
    for just_tall in items:
        if just_tall.get('property') == 'tall': 
            print just_tall.get('property')
        if just_tall.get('name') == 'tall':
            print just_tall.get('name')
except:
    print ""
```

Output:

```
#How can I find all of the instances of property?
<meta property="tall"/>
<meta content="spiral" property="wide"/>

#How can I then extract tall and wide?
tall
wide

#all of the instances of tall
[<meta property="tall"/>]
[<meta name="tall"/>]

#How can I then extract tall?
tall
tall
```

Rest is all playing around but the above will help you get started. Some questions are still ambiguous so I gave you some example above to help you.

Tutorial and More examples: [Link to docs](http://www.nyu.edu/projects/politicsdatalab/workshops/BeautifulSoup.pdf)